# how to disable an option with msdropdown plugin

Tags: javascript, html, msdropdown

Is it possible to disable an option after creating a msDropdown plugin?

I explain my problem better.
I want to put html into each option with icons, text and some other stuff, so first i create an empty select then I add each option with the **add** function:

```
dropdown.add({text:$price.html(), value:'normal', className:'normal'});
```

The problem is that if a certain condition happen I have to disable one option, but there are no way to set an option *disabled* by using plugin settings.

There is the possibility to make an option disabled only by setting the related parameter `disabled=disabled` into the *select* before to call the **msDropdown** function, but I can't use this solution since I have to put dinamically *html* into option text.

Is there another way to do it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "msdropdown plugin"? Is there some sort of proprietary Microsoft plugin you're referring to?

Comment: No, I think he means this plugin: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Comment: Exaclty, I mean [marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown](http://marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).
Excuse me if I didn't said it before. I edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @werner Answer edited; take a look at it; try setting disabled: true property in the add method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I create my select empty and I fill each option with **add** function as before, but when that condition happen just do this:

```
var dropdown = $('select[name="priceType"]').msDropdown().data("dd");

if(credits_error) { // option must be disabled
    dropdown.destroy(); // Make it a simple select
    $('select[name="priceType"] option').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    dropdown = $('select[name="priceType"]').msDropdown().data("dd");
}
```

This way first I make it a simple *select* by calling **destroy** function, then I set properly the disabled attribute and I create a new **msDropdown select**.

It works for me, I tested it on IE, FF and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possibile. It can be done by using the `disabled` property of the option tag:

```
<select id="payments" name="payments" style="width:250px;">
    <option value="" data-description="Choos your payment gateway">Payment Gateway</option>
    <option value="amex" data-image="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/images/msdropdown/icons/Amex-56.png" data-description="My life. My card...">Amex</option>
    <option value="Discover" data-image="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/images/msdropdown/icons/Discover-56.png" data-description="It pays to Discover...">Discover</option>
    <option value="Mastercard" data-image="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/images/msdropdown/icons/Mastercard-56.png" data-title="For everything else..." data-description="For everything else...">Mastercard</option>
    <option value="cash" data-image="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/images/msdropdown/icons/Cash-56.png" data-description="Sorry not available..." disabled="true">Cash on devlivery</option>
    <option value="Visa" data-image="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/images/msdropdown/icons/Visa-56.png" data-description="All you need...">Visa</option>
    <option value="Paypal" data-image="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/images/msdropdown/icons/Paypal-56.png" data-description="Pay and get paid...">Paypal</option>
</select>
```

The option 'cash' will be disabled.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NKQRj/1/

EDIT
In this second example data are loaded from JSON data using:

```
$("#payments").msDropDown({byJson:{data:jsonData, name:'payments2'}}).data("dd");
```

to fill the elements.

You can define your options as disabled in your JSON data using `disabled: true` property:

```
{image:'http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/images/msdropdown/icons/Cash-56.png', description:'Sorry not available...', value:'cash', text:'Cash on devlivery', disabled:true},
```

here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NKQRj/3/

Comment: the problem is more complex. I can change the property _disabled_ from **disabled** to **enabled** dinamically if a condition is verified. In your example i set in json data if it is disabled on not and that's it

Comment: Now is clear; in the question was not clear that the disabling of an option happens at run time.
Your final solution is right